# NumPy fancy indexing assignment: possible to specify reducer for overlapping targets?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to use NumPy to copy data from a set of buffers onto possibly-overlapping locations in a target array. The mapping is defined by an array of target indexes. I would like to customize the behavior when the target indexes are overlapping. Here is an example:

- `buffers` - shape (48,15), each location is a "pixel" between 0-1.
- `output` - shape (600,). A 1-D array of pixel values.
- `buffer_mappings` - shape (48,15). Each `buffer_mappings[i,j]` provides a scalar index `k`, specifying that `buffers[i,j]` should be painted at location `output[k]`.

Currently I've been using fancy indexing as follows.

`output[buffer_mappings] = buffers`

The problem arises when multiple inputs from `buffers` are mapped to the same `output` location. Fancy indexing will only use the last input value for a given location. How can I provide a reducer, say `max` or `avg`, when this happens? See the desired behavior:

[image: illustration]

Maybe this isn't possible using fancy indexing; I'm open to other approaches as well.

Comment: `ufunc` like `add` have an unbuffered method, `.at`.  Look up `np.add.at`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hpaulj for the pointer to `ufunc.at`! The following works for "max" accumulation:

```
output = np.zeros(600)
np.maximum.at(output, buffer_mappings, buffers)
```

To average the overlapping values, I think this will work:

```
output = np.zeros(600)
np.add.at(output, buffer_mappings, buffers)
counts = np.bincount(buffer_mappings.ravel(), minlength=600)
np.divide(output, counts, out=output, where=counts!=0)
```